# File upload to Amazon S3 using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading files to S3 using `paperclip` so would like to know if i can set the path something like,

```
:path => "/advertisements/:username/:filename”
```

the thing is that `:usename` is from other model; i'm uploading files on `model_2` and `:username` comes from `model_1`. How can i set the path to indicate the `:username`

**Sample**:

```
:path => "/advertisements/@model_1.username/:filename”
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is nice explanation:**

please view the answer.

[Rails 4, Paperclip, Amazon S3 Config Amazon Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348886/rails-4-paperclip-amazon-s3-config-amazon-path)

**Model:**

```
#Image Upload 
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick'
has_attached_file :image,
        :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
        :default_url => "****",
        :storage => :s3,
        :bucket => '****',
        :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
            :url => "/:image/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
            :path => ":image/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

**config/application.rb**

```
# Paperclip (for Amazon) (we use EU servers)
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
  }
```

**config/s3.yml**

## Amazon AWS Config

```
development:
  access_key_id: **********
  secret_access_key: **************
  bucket: ****

production:
  access_key_id: ***********
  secret_access_key: ***********
  bucket: ****
```

I hope this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: Thank You Very much! You're awesome! :D